# Spatie Sitemap not generating URLs on localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-sitemap

I am creating a website in Laravel 5.8 and using Spatie sitemap package to create Sitemap dynamically, It doesn't crawl my website and only generates homepage URL.

```
Route::get('/sitemap',function(){
    SitemapGenerator::create( 'http://localhost/' )->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
})->name('sitemap-generator');
```

Note: But when I map website with a virtual host, It is working properly.

```
Route::get('/sitemap',function(){
    SitemapGenerator::create( 'http://local.project.com/' )->writeToFile('sitemap.xml');
})->name('sitemap-generator');
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I know this may be almost insultingly stupid to ask... But can you visit the website from that URL in your browser? (this is the proverbial "have you turned it off and on again" question)

Comment: Yes, I was able to visit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use **port** with localhost. In my case port was **8000**.

```
SitemapGenerator::create('http://localhost:8000')
            ->writeToFile(public_path('sitemap.xml'));
```

This worked for me.

Comment: what about when using valet?